# Find the distribution of $\beta$ after observing $X=x.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Assume that $X\sim\text{exp}(\beta),$ where $\beta$ itself is a random
>   variable with $\sim\text{exp}(1).$ Determine the distribution of
>   $\beta$ after we have observed $X=x.$

We have that $f_{X|\beta}(x|\beta)=\beta e^{-\beta x}$, $f_{\beta}(\beta)=e^{-\beta}$ and we are looking for $f_{\beta|X}(\beta|x).$ From Baye's we have that

$$f_{\beta|X}(\beta|x)=Cf_{X|\beta}(x|\beta)f_\beta(\beta)=C\beta e^{-\beta x}e^-{\beta}=C\beta e^{-(x+1)\beta}, \ \beta>0$$

and $C$ is a constant. This is a distribution with no famous name. I'd like to be done here but according to the book the answer is that

$$f_{\beta|X}(\beta|x)=(x+1)^2\beta e^{(x+1)\beta},$$

so $\beta\sim\Gamma(2,x+1)$. They come to this conclusion by integrating:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\beta e^{-(x+1)\beta} \ d\beta=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}.$$

I have no idea what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

They are trying to find  the value of the constant $C$. Since $f_{\beta \mid X}$ is a density it is the case that
$$
\int_{0}^\infty C\beta e^{-(x+1)\beta}\, d\beta=1\implies C=\left[
\int_{0}^\infty \beta e^{-(x+1)\beta}\, d\beta
\right]^{-1}=(x+1)^2.
$$

Comment: But ofcourse! thanks!

Comment: But shoudn't the exponent in the answer then be negative?

Comment: @Parseval Yes I would think so. Perhaps it is a typo

Comment: Yes, might be. But now the gamma dsitribution is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}$$ and my answer is the above. How do I know that in my case the parameters are $2$ and $x+1$? I can't rewrite the anwer in the same form as the distribution in order to compare parameters.